# how to remove 'escape slash' in json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapes, strip

I need to remove escape sequence. How can I do it using python?

- Current results

```
"conv": "\"XXXXX\"",
```

- After shaping(I want to get this)

```
"conv": "XXXXX",
```

Comment: this may well be a problem of how json is being created in the first place

Comment: parse the json and then use `strip()` like this `d['conv'].strip('"')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
import json
x = {"conv": "\"XXXXX\""}
x['conv'] = json.loads(x['conv']) # sets conv to "XXXXX"
```

Comment: NO. If you do a `json.loads` against the OP's input, the value of the conv key is *not* "XXXX'.

Comment: My answer was to give a general idea of the utility of json decoder. I've updated the code to reflect the exact scenario, which does work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-up on the back-slashes, otherwise you will not end up with something that will parse as json because otherwise you are just replacing all `"` characters and leaving the backslash:

```
s = s.replace('\\"', '')
```

```
import json


d = {"conv": "\"XXXXX\""}
s = json.dumps(d)
print(s) # -> {"conv": "\"XXXXX\""}
s = s.replace('\\"', '')
print(s) # -> {"conv": "XXXXX"}
print(json.loads(s)) # -> {'conv': 'XXXXX'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `replace`

```
conv = "\"XXXXX\""
conv = conv.replace("\"", "")
```

Comment: You are testing against a 5-character string of all X's. What type of test is this? Have you tested against the actual input?

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly but I don't understand why \" inside quotes? if we are searching for \ isn't it supposed to be \\ ? isn;t "\"" saying take " as literal string?

Answer (score -1):

You can remove string using `str.replace` method.

```
'\"XXXXX\"'.replace("\"","") # returns 'XXXXX'
```

Here's how to use [str.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)

Comment: But the actual input to test is `'"\"XXXXX\""'.replace("\"","")` because everything is within one big JSON string.